# Frontend won't load JS or CSS

Tags: magento-2.1, windows, frontend-error

After running **magento setup:upgrade** i got this following error in command line:

```
[Exception]
  Missing write permissions to the following paths:
  C:/xampp/htdocs/magento2/pub/static\frontend\Magento\luma\en_US
```

and after i run **magento setup:static-content:deploy** and delete my browser cache, my backend is fine but my frontend page wont load any css or js, when i look at the console there are a lot of error saying:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run following command from command line :

```
chmod -R 777 var/
chmod -R 777 pub/
```

Comment: sorry i'm still in stone age era and using windows :D